# InvalidSelectorException occurs when trying to locate an element with ID--selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
question = driver.find_element('id', '//*[@id=question]')
question.get_attribute('value')
```

I'm trying to get the value of the element with `id='question'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Syntax is wrong, try the below

```
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
question = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'question')
question.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: This would work if you are finding the element by Xpath. But as it's written now you're looking for an element with `id='//*[@id=question]'`, which quite certainly does not exist.

Comment: Oh mistake - you're right I corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix. You need to import and use By in order to create a valid selector. Also, you've not assigned the `value` attribute to any variable; I would suggest you try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.implicitly_wait(2)
question = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'question')
value = question.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: Great! If you may, please "accept" the answer to indicate that your problem is solvecd.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify according to which criteria you want to [locate the element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html?highlight=xpath#locating-by-xpath).

So for example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

question = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=question]')
id = question.get_attribute('id')
```

or in one line:

```
id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=question]').get_attribute('id')
```

P.s: I suggest you to always use [explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of implicit ones.

Comment: Can you explain why "Xpath is the preferred one"?

Comment: Simply because it is the most powerful way to locate items. You are able to apply operators like contains() to it.
I also think that a code where it is used Xpath only is much easier to be read than a code where elements are located in many different ways (id, name, etc). And xpath is the only one that let you locate every single element.
Anything can be located through it and you cannot say the same for the others.
But, well, it's a personal thing I guess. I will edit the comment.

Comment: This makes sense. I disagree that the Xpath is normally easiest to read, and to my knowledge it is the slowest way to identify an element in most circumstances--this is why, unless you've specified Xpath as a selector, Selenium uses CSS selectors under the hood when you choose to locate via ID, name, etc. Thus, I personally prefer to use CSS selectors directly whenever possible. To each their own.

 In any case, writing `id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=question]').get_attribute('id')` will simply return `'question'`, which would be quite useless.

Comment: I think you wrote you wanted the value of the id attribute and then edit the question. Or maybe I simply misread lol. 
So, assuming the value of the element is text, it would be: `question = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=question]').text`


If instead you mean the value of the attribute named value: `question = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=question]').get_attribute('value')`